# Any PHP framework using latest mongodb driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, frameworks

Am searching for PHP framework which supports PHP7 and latest php mongo driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) using 1.1.8 (https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)

I tried with codeignitor and fatfree but they seems to support old one. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Zeeshan

Comment: I'm not sure about 1.1.8 but Yii 2 should work with 1.1.7 so just check this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb

Comment: Yes @Bizley it does support latest mongo driver, thanks will check that.

Comment: I feel Yii is bit difficult to understand (may be because am new to frameworks)

Comment: I think this Yii 2 guide is really good http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

Comment: While Doctrine's ODM (https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm) does not support new driver directly yet, it's possible to combine these two using a polyfill like https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter

Comment: You can use library in any framework and use it. I am using it with codeigninter 3. You can isntall it through composer $ composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0" and follow steps from here to use it http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/getting-started/

Comment: @SohailAnwar can you please give me exact steps how to load this library in codeignitor?

Comment: Why does this get downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using codeignitor then you can install library through composer (you need to install composer first if you dont have)

Then go to your project directory through command line and run the following command

```
composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0
```

It will install mongodb library in your vendor folder of your project.
Then you need to include following line where you want to use the library for eg you can include it on top of your controller or model.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Sorry but i am new to framework, i installed the above library successfully and its working as well. Just have 1 doubt this can not be used as active records rights we need to create a separate library file for active records?

Comment: @Zeeshan yes you are right you can use it directly now otherwise you have to create a separate library if for active records.

Comment: Thanks @Sohail for the information, let me know if you know any such library that can be used with codeignitor. Meanwhile am trying to modify this library https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library

Comment: @Zeeshan  github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library  this library uses old driver previously i have used this in one of my projects. If you can modify it for new driver it will be great i guess you have to rewrite it.

Comment: Yes @Sohail, its using old driver am rewriting to match with the new one. Hope for the best :)

Comment: For those who are searching for Codeignitor library with new mongodb, i have updated [here](https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library)

Till the time pull request is merged to master you can refer the pull request directly (https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library/pull/16)